# Alphavantage and NASDAQ Index stopped working

Tags: alpha-vantage

This API call for NASDAQ Composite used to work.  Now it returns just an empty JSON.  `{}`.  No error message.

```
https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_MONTHLY&symbol=IXIC&apikey=your_api_key
```

Other indices seem to work OK eg  `DJI`, `SPX`

An email to support has not been answered.

Anyone have any more information on this?

Comment: I see the same thing.  One interesting thing I've found is that you can make that request repeatedly (I tried it 100 times in a row) without getting rate limited.  It's like that symbol sends the request into a black hole.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*UPDATE*

### The trick below has stopped working.  Hopefully Alpha Vantage will regain their access to the NASDAQ soon.

Try replacing `IXIC` with `NASDAQ:^IXIC`

[https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_MONTHLY&symbol=NASDAQ:^IXIC&apikey=your_api_key](https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_MONTHLY&symbol=NASDAQ:%5EIXIC&apikey=your_api_key)

Comment: Thank you. +1 as that symbol does return values!, but only integer values are returned (not sure if they are rounded or truncated). Better than nothing, but would be nice to get the actual values.  And, it seems the `^` can be omitted.

Comment: Does it work for DAILY? i tried your URL, didnt seem to work, i got a {}

Comment: Even this technique no longer works for me.  I now too get a {}

Comment: @Andrew Stone NDAQ is the symbol for the company that operates the Nasdaq stock exchange, not the Nasdaq Composite index.

Comment: What the hack is going on at Alpha Vantage API..!!?