# Alpha Vantage API not returning Nasdaq quotes

Tags: alpha-vantage

The Alpha Vantage API doesn't deliver quotes for the NASDAQ Index (anymore?). All other indizes that I'm interested in seem to work like a charm.

For example calling the following URL (API Key masked) will deliver the quote for the S&P (symbol `^GSPC`):

`https://www.alphavantage.co/query?symbol=%5EGSPC&apikey=123456789&outputsize=compact&datatype=csv&function=GLOBAL_QUOTE`

I already came across [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54751839/alphavantage-and-nasdaq-index-stopped-working), that describes the exact thing. The solution using the symbol `^IXIC` doesn't seem to work however (neither `IXIC`). All I get is `{}`.

Are some indizes like NASDAQ just not supported or is there any other symbol I have to take.

Comment: did you find out the solution?

Answer (score 1):

It's the other way around, they support stock tickers, and if they happen to have indexes, that's a bonus.

To quote the site:

```
Alpha Vantage APIs are grouped into four categories: (1) Stock Time Series Data, (2) Physical and Digital/Crypto Currencies (e.g., Bitcoin), (3) Technical Indicators, and (4) Sector Performances.
```

It doesn't mention indexes.

Answer (score 1):

I've been using this for TouchDesigner, and so far NASDAQ is the only index that seems to not be supported.

```
{
#Stock index symbols
NYSE = '^NYA'
TSX = '^GSPTSE'
SP_500 = '^GSPC'
DowJones = '^DJI'
Russell = '^RUT'
#NASDAQ INDEX MISSING
#NASDAQ = '^IXIC'
Nikkei = '^N225'
Bovespa = '^BVSP'
SP_BMV = '^MXX'
DAX = '^GDAXI'
FTSE = '^FTSE'
HangSeng = '^HSI'
China = 'XIN9.FGI'
BSE = '^BSESN'
KOSPI = '^KS11'
SP_ASX = '^AXJO'
FTSE_JSE = 'J203.L'
}
```